# If, else statement issue in r

Tags: r, if-statement, printing

I am trying to filter and label three categories: "High", "Low", and "Other" based on two columns, "Metering" and "Taskload".

Here is my code:

```
WorkloadCategory <- function(Metering, Taskload) 
  if(Metering == "7"/"M" & (Taskload > median_taskload) 
   print("High")
  if(Metering == "1"/"3" & (Taskload < median_taskload)
   print("Low")
  if_else  
   print("Other")
```

I am having some difficulty doing this as the "If else" statement isn't working. All the other statements are working.  When I add } to my code, it pulls up an error message and says "unexpected symbol: }"

Any suggestions would be so helpful!! Thank you so much

Comment: Please show a small reprodcuoible example with `dput`  The values `c("7"/"M")` doesn't look correct.  Also, you may need `ifelse` instead of `if/else`

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean.  I've also tried if_else and that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: what I meant is that we cannot test your code without an example data

Comment: btw, `if_else` technically *is* a function found in R, specifically the `dplyr` package, but it does not belong where you use it. (I think Bryan's answer is sufficient to address most of your needs, just thought I'd add that bit.)

Answer (score 1):

You missed some key "`(`" in your if examples.  I also do not know what `"7"/"M"` does on your machine as on mine it always returns an error.  I assume you are asking the function if the metering falls `%in%` either of these strings, therefore I rewrote the function to be the function below.  Please comment your questions before a downvote if this answer misses the mark.

Additionally, your function calls upon an undefined variable from the outside environment, `median_taskload`, my function asks for that variable.

```
 WorkloadCategory <- function(Metering, Taskload, median_taskload){
  high_metering <- c("7", "M")
  low_metering <- c("1", "3")
  if( Metering %in% high_metering & (Taskload > median_taskload) ){
     print("High")
  } else if( Metering %in% low_metering & (Taskload < median_taskload) ){
     print("Low")
  } else
    print("Other")
}

WorkloadCategory("7", 8, 2) 
# [1] "High"
WorkloadCategory("M", 8, 8) # Taskload is equal to the median
# [1] "Other" 
WorkloadCategory("3", 1, 2)
# [1] "Low"
```

Comment: One should never use `&` in an `if` conditional: while it technically works, `&` implies the arguments can be of length *"zero or more"*, whereas `if` requires length 1. (The only advantage I see of using `&` in place of `&&` in an `if` statement is that with `&`, R warns about "condition has length > 1", whereas with `&&` it may just silently do something else. Perhaps that's enough ...)

Comment: This is a great note, @r2evans  .  I am still not certain of the OPs original question / function and tried to keep to their format as closely as I could.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  My manager gave me this code and I was responsible for inputting the correct terminology so altering the structure significantly was not an option. Thanks again for everyone's help!

Comment: You're welcome, if my function satisfies your use case, could you please select it as the best answer?  Thanks.

Comment: Cath, what do you consider *"altering the structure significantly"*? As it stands, the original code is both invalid syntax and error-prone.

Comment: Hi @r2evans, I am a beginning coder so I am unsure how to fix the code above.  How would you write it? Thanks so much